# "Не()слишком"

Tags: орфография

Есть ли ситуации, когда "не()слишком", выступая в роли наречия, пишется слитно? Например: "Он не()слишком высокий для своего возраста".
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, наречие *неслишком* словарями не зафиксировано.

Comment: А жаль))) Я все норовлю написать слитно, а все ворды в один голос орут, что такого слова нет)))  
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Словарями-то зафиксировано, но только старыми (Брокгауза и Ефрона, Даля).

Comment: Гм... выходит, так все-таки можно писать, но это будет устаревший вариант?

Comment: Слишком устаревший; теперь — неправильный.

Comment: Словарь Брокгауза и Ефрона не лингвистический, поэтому ссылаться на него в плане правописания нельзя. Словарь Даля фиксирует орфографическую норму позапрошлого века. В общем случае обращаться за нормами правописания к словарям, вышедшим до «Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 г., едва ли разумно.